# Selecting an element not equal to a certain string

Tags: cypress

I am trying to select an incorrect answer (radio button) to get an error message to appear, but the answers are random (except the correct answer).

How can I say get the radio buttons, and then click one that does not equal "correct answer" using cypress assertions?

```
cy.get('[data-cy="multipleChoiceQuestionAnswer"]')
        .should('not.contain', 'correct answer')//.find('label').not('corect answer')//.not.includes('correct answer')
.click()
```

I would like to be able to select one of the two radio buttons for the incorrect answers, right now I can only select the correct answer.

Comment: If you came up with a different solution, please share it with us  or accept my answer, both could be useful for other users 

Answer (score 1):

well:

- be aware that `.should('not.contain', 'correct answer')` is an assertion, is not a way to filter/get some elements.
  It's, essentially, just a way to check (aka "assert") that something is like you expect it to be.
  An assertion like yours is useful just to get the Cypress log print something like this
  [image]
  Read it like if you are telling

> "Ehy Cypress, I selected an element, could you check that it doesn't contain the *correct answer*, please?"

- What are assertions useful for? They aren't useful when everything goes right but when the test goes wrong.
  Because without assertions, you can find yourself behind a broken test with Cypress telling you that "there isn't the element" but you can't know which element Cypress isn't finding.
  Placing some "key point" assertions allows you to understand why a test failed in short time.

Anyway: if your HTML is something like this

```html
<div data-cy="multipleChoiceQuestionAnswer"><label>correct answer<input type="checkbox"/></label></div>
<div data-cy="multipleChoiceQuestionAnswer"><label>no<input type="checkbox"/></label></div>
<div data-cy="multipleChoiceQuestionAnswer"><label>nope<input type="checkbox"/></label></div>
```

you can accomplish your goal making:

```
cy.get('[data-cy="multipleChoiceQuestionAnswer"]').then(els => {
  // `els` is a jQuery instance, let's parse the various elements
  let $el;
  for(let i = 0, n = els.length; i < n; i++) {
    // it transforms every element in a jQuery instance
    $el = Cypress.$(els[i]);
    // it uses jQuery to get the label text
    if($el.find("label").text() !== "correct answer") {
      // it stops as soon as the answer isn't the correct one
      break;
    }
  }
  // returns the element to be clicked
  return $el.find("input");
})
// it assert about it (to have a useful hint in the Cypress command log)
.should("not.contain", "correct answer")
// clicks it
.click();
```

I hope the code is self-explanatory (in case it isn't, ask me some more clarifications)